# How to add Promoted links web part to page and set JSLink

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to deploy a Promoted links web par to the default.aspx page, following the article from Muawiyah Shannak http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sharepoint-2013-How-to-add-e2966a24#content
But I cant find out how to set the JSLink url in the markup.

```
<div> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone" runat="server" FrameType="None"> 
            <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart 
               ID="XsltListViewArticlePromotedList" 
                runat="server" 
                ListUrl="Lists/MyPromotedLinks" 
                IsIncluded="True" 
                NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" 
                Title="Images used in switcher" 
                PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" 
                Default="False" 
                ViewContentTypeId="0x"> 
            </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart> 
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[XsltListWebPart.JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) sets CSR file to rendering the List View:

```
<JSLink>~site/SiteAssets/PromotedLinks.js</JSLink>
```

where `~site` is a URL token.

Please refer [URLs and tokens in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx) for a more details.